# Where is the option to add a new preference screen in Android Studio 0.4.0?

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 0.4.0
```

Hello,

I want to add a new Preference Screen in Android Studio. However, I cannot find the menu option to do it.

In Eclipse you would right click the resource directory | New xml file | resource type (preferences)

However, when I try and do this in Android Studio, there is no resource type `preferences`.

Do I have to do this manually now?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The preference option doesn't exist anymore. You will need to right click the `res`->`new`->`Android resource file` and choose the resource type as `xml` in the dropdown. Then you will manually need to add the layout for preference xml.

Comment: Why is that? Is this not the official way for a settings menu anymore?

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio 1.1.0:
If you create a SettingsActivity it automatically sets up some xml preference resource files for you.

1. Under src > main > java, right click a package (e.g. com.company.appname)
2. New > Activity > Settings Activity
3. Click Finish to accept the defaults
4. Notice the new files:

   - SettingsActivity
   - values/strings_activity_settings.xml
   - xml (Directory)

     - pref_data_sync.xml
     - pref_general.xml
     - pref_headers.xml
     - pref_notification.xml

Note: The Activity uses some deprecated code. It might be best to look at the latest documentation for creating a preferences activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html and for creating the XML resource file: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html

Comment: so nice i did not thing about using adding new Activity from there.

Answer (score 3):

What I just did was creating a new "Android resource directory" res->new->Android resource directory. There you choose xml, which creates the xml folder. Right click on this xml folder -> new -> XML resource file and then it proposes Preference Screen.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Android Studio 1.0.2. File ->New->Other. Select Activity->Settings Activity. Follow the wizard to add it to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Folder/Directory -> New -> Xml Resource File.
Name the File and create. This will create Preference xml file.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows,
Go to Settings
Then Double Click on Editor

Answer (score 1):

(For Windows, go to File > Settings > Editor > General)
(For Mac, go to Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > General)

Answer (score 1):

In AS 3.2, click on `res/xml`, type ALT INS, select ***`XML Resource File`*** and you get an empty `PreferencesScreen`