# No visual editing of preferences screen anymore?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-preferences

I wanted to add a settings menu to my android app.

I followed this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

and added an "activity_settings.xml" in "res/xml/" like descripted.
But now I cannot edit with the WYSIWYG editor?

Why is that? Isn't google supporting this way of creating settings anymore?
How else should I do it? Create a "normal" activity layout file and use this as menu?

Found this, but no answer why:
[Where is the option to add a new preference screen in Android Studio 0.4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720667/where-is-the-option-to-add-a-new-preference-screen-in-android-studio-0-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has never been a visual editor for PreferenceScreen.

It is an xml file of preferences that are bound to an activity on run time.
I dont see anywhere in the official docs you linked that supports the idea of a visual editor.

You can edit visually, any activity layouts, but this has always (to my understanding) been different.
I can see where you are coming from though, at it is still an xml in a layout kind of structure.

Your best solution is to run your project periodically to see the progress.